# What will happen when we modify manifest of an existing Office add-in?

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-app

I have an Office add-in available in the store. Currently, part of its manifest file is

```
<Requirements>
  <Sets>
    <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.2"/>
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

I want to change it to the follows, and expect this will make the add-in available in `Office Professional Plus 2016`.

```
<Requirements>
  <Sets>
    <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

So after submitting the new manifest, will the add-in be re-validated again? During this period, will the existing add-in be still usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any change to the manifest requires re-validation before publishing.

When you submit your updated add-in for validation, the existing version remains available.

Comment: What will happen to the existing reviews? Will they remain?

Comment: If you are submitting an update to an existing add-in, reviews will not be affected.